# Jekyll not generating index.html in subdirectory

Tags: markdown, jekyll

I have a website (http://3.128.203.103/) I'm working on generating with Jekyll.

There is a subdirectory, /roundup, which contains a list of newsletters.
The newsletters are being coded in Markdown (I'm slowly translating from HTML).

There is an index file, index.md, which contains an index to all the issue files.

But when I run "Jekyll build", it generates the issue HTML files (205.md to 213.md become 205.html to 213.html) -- but not index.html.

In the *main* root directory, it generates index.html from an index.md - but not in the /roundup subdirectory.

Any suggestions?